# Let's go on a mission

Tags: discussion, editing, quality

Islam.SE has been growing at a pretty good pace. As of this post, [here are our stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14922/islam):

- 3.4 questions per day *(needs improvement)*
- 89% answered *(okay)*
- 1471 users, 117 avid users *(okay)*
- 2.1 question to answer ratio *(okay)*
- 2396 views per day *(excellent)*

Pretty good right?

## What do I want to do?

Well, I want to go on a mission. A mission to make all of those stats rise as much as we can, in a  short period of time. More specifically, ***I want 3/5 of those stats to be excellent by August 8 (Eid al-Fitr).*** Not just good, excellent.

## That's going to be pretty hard...

Maybe, if this was any other beta site on the network. This site has one of the best communities in the network. Although we don't have many users, the users we have are very active. Because of that, I think this goal is very possible.

But I'm not done. Now, let's look at the long term goals.

## Wait, you have long-term goals too?

Yes, I do.

My long term goal is probably the most important one. We need to improve the quality of posts. We have to realize that a lot of our sit'es users are not native English speakers. Because of this, a lot of their posts, although they are very informative, do not use proper grammar, spelling, etc. We can't teach people English, so we need to do something else.

***We need to consistently edit all posts that are not using proper English.***

For those of you who's first language is not English, *please keep posting*. Please. We need the information that you're giving us. All I ask is that you try as hard as possible to use the best English you know.

## Okay so I know what to do... now how do I do it?

Well, let's take this one topic at a time:

- **Ask more questions!** If you have a good, genuine question that will benefit the site, don't be afraid to ask it!
- **If you see a question, only answer it if you can back it up.** Again, only answer the question if you know what you're talking about. We want to see answer based on authentic Islamic teachings. I'm not telling anybody to answer fewer questions, just make sure you're using authentic sources.
- **Tell your friends!** We want as many users as possible! Go to work, school, the mosque, church, the grocery store, wherever! We want a very diverse set of users so no matter who your friends are, tell them about our site!
- **Edit as many posts as you can.** We want our site to be *the* source for Islamic Q&A. To do that we need do things: quality and quantity. By editing posts, you are helping the users who are providing the information by cleaning it up for them.

## Are you done?

Yes, I'm done. I'm sure you guys know all of the stuff that I just wrote. The community is running strong so you must have.

Now go out there and make Islam.SE, and the internet, a better place.

Comment: There will be a spike in many of those stats and in new visitors come Ramadan. We could also look at retaining those new visitors and the old members who are revisiting.